# PHP Get value from json ticker

Tags: php, json

Ticker:

```
{"high": "145.00", "last": "143.92", "timestamp": "1382049657", "bid": "143.81", "volume": "17883.09636191", "low": "135.00", "ask": "143.92"}
```

How i can get "ask" value from this ticket?

I use this code to get it:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$getit= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $getit;
```

Answer (score 2):

The website response is in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you must first decode it into an array, using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode).

```
$ticket = json_decode($getit, true);

echo $ticket['ask'];
```